# How can I convert a varchar into a date in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

Probably it's super simple but i've been stuck some hours on this.
I have a column called "Publish_Date" which is a varchar, but my date shows like this: 17.01.11 (year.day.month) and I want to convert it to a date (at this point, any date format it's ok).

Every time i tried to use "convert" or "cast" it gives me a syntax error or the data doesn't change or all the data in the column changes to "null" values.
I'd appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: You shouldn't be fine with _"any date format"_ though, because there's a lot of convenient MySQL date functions you can use if you're using the MySQL standard date format (`YYYY-MM-DD`). Of course, you can always convert it first but you can see that `YEAR(correct_date)` is much shorter than `YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(Publish_Date, '%y.%m.%d'))`. If it's possible, you should add a `DATE` datatype column in your table and update it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is all greater than 2000 then you can add missing part of YEAR then cast it.

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT('20', Publish_Date) AS DATETIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://mysqlcode.com/mysql-str-to-date/) with the format `%y.%m.%d` since this is how your date value is stored

```
select 
 
  str_to_date(birth_date, '%y.%m.%d')
from 
   mytable
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40918c/5) I created for this case